# Message box vba

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me in correcting the below VBA code for excel 2007. Somebody had provided me this code in one of the forum which suits my need. But I am getting some problem while I run this code. Since I am not a programmer it could not be rectified. So please help to overcome this.

The problem is.... message is popping up from begin to end continuously.
For Example: If the value of cell "P7" reaches above 0 say to 1, I get the popup message which is fine. But some times the value of the cell keeps fluctuating above 0 like from 1 to 2, 2 to 2.5 or 3.......so on as the cell value is derived from the calculation of other cells (real time data). Due to this I am getting the popup message for each successive increase in the cell value.
It should popup only when the cell value goes above 0 but not for every further increment like from 0.5 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 2.5 or 3.....
Further to the above problem, I have noticed that, if for example the cell value "P7" crosses above 0 say to 1.5 and stays there and subsequently the cell value of "P8" or "P9" or both reaches above 0, I am also getting the popup message of "P7" along with "P8" and "P9" instead of only "P8" or "P9".

Below is the code for your reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
    'Dimension variables
    Dim c As Range, Str1 As String

    'Set up a range to loop thru
    For Each c In Range("P7:P77,S7:S77")
        'Test if that cell contains a number >0
        If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Value > 0 Then
            'Which column are we in to calculate
            'The offset to column U and decide whether
            'to use Buy or Sell as our string
            Select Case c.Column
                Case Is = 16
                    Str1 = "Buy "
                    oset = 5
                Case Is = 19
                    Str1 = "Sell "
                    oset = 2
            End Select

           'Popup the message box
            MsgBox Str1 & c.Offset(, oset)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not a programmer either, however a certain level of understanding coding is expected here. For sovling this it will go beyond the first basics I fear. With that in mind this is my answer to your question.

Solve this by doing 2 things:

1. Storing the state of the ranges before they change
2. Have a Status to indicate you are already in this check and thus dont want it to be activated again

**PART 1 Storing the state**

**Store the state** of the ranges you check in the same subroutine, either by copying those cells to a part of the workbook that is not used or store them in de VBA code as Public Variables

Then in addition to checking `If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Value > 0` you will need to check if the number in the last time you stored it was <=0. So your If statement would become something like:

```
If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Value > 0 And d.Value <= 0 Then
```

Where `d` is your copy cell. You need to determine where these cells are placed (preferably with a fixed offset, or on a hidden sheet in the exact same cell!

Or with a public variable pubVar() with dimensions 7 to 77, 16 to 19, which can be dimensioned at Workbook_Open:

```
If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Value > 0 And pubVar(c.Row(), c.Column())<= 0 Then
```

Now whichever route you take you need to include at the end of your script a section to actually store the state of your cells, with a `Range("P7:P77,S7:S77").Copy`  and paste the values to `Range(<where you want it>).PasteSpecial ...`. Or by assigning the values to the variable, like a `Variant`

**PART 2 Having a status**

To **have a Status** you can use a public variable, I would take a Boolean  called booAlreadyChecking, and have a check on that Boolean + a code to change its value wrapped around your current code:

```
If Not booAlreadyChecking Then 'Check if there is already another check running
    booAlreadyChecking = True 'Indicate that there is already a check so not another one will be started 
    For Each c In Range("P7:P77,S7:S77")
        ...
    Next
    booAlreadyChecking = False 'Enable a new check once this one is completed
End If
```